# Creating a Security Group with Owner doesn't work using Service Principal in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to create an Azure security group across PowerShell and connected with a service principal.

My service principal has a Custom Role with **microsoft.directory/groups/create** permission allowing me to create Security Groups and Microsoft 365 groups, excluding role-assignable groups.

I'm using Microsoft.Graph.Groups module in PowerShell and I gave my service principal good rights to use Graph API.

When I create an empty security group with the command

```
New-MgGroup -BodyParameter $params
```

with

```
$params = @{
>>         description = "Group with designated owner DJER0105"
>>         displayName = "Group Test 20-07"
>>         mailEnabled = $false
>>         mailNickname = "GroupTest20-07"
>>         securityEnabled = $true
>>     }
```

My request pass without problems, BUT when I try to put an Owner I got a 403 error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

```
$params =  @{
>>         description = "Group with designated owner DJER0105"
>>         displayName = "Group Test 20-07"
>>         mailEnabled = $false
>>         mailNickname = "GroupTest20-07"
>>         securityEnabled = $true
>>         **"owners@odata.bind" = @(
>>             "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/47f89f36-2ad7-45ee-a1ac-3cd0b0e021df"**
>>         )
>>     }
```

Does someone have any idea why I can't perform this action (security group creation with owner) using the service principal?

I already tried to do the same but with a nominative account (user account) which works well in both cases.

I tried to add the owner after creation like this:

`$params = @{ "@odata.id" = "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users{id}" }`

`New-MgGroupOwnerByRef -GroupId $groupId -BodyParameter $params`

And I got same error 403 "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

For information I don't need to be the owner of the security group, I want to create a security group and put another user as owner.

Comment: Does it work if you create the group first (without specifying the owner), and then [set the owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&source=recommendations&tabs=powershell#example) manually afterwards?

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work neither. I tried 

$params = @{
 "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
}

New-MgGroupOwnerByRef -GroupId $groupId -BodyParameter $params

And I got same error 403 "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Creating a Security Group with Owner doesn't work using Service Principal in PowerShell

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

I created an application with API permission **`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`** with granted admin consent.

[image]

Now, I tried with the below command it created the group with the owner.

**Command:**

```
$tenantId ="your-tenant-id"
$appId = "your-client-id"
$ownerObjectId = "user object id"
$groupName = "Testvenkatgrp"
$groupDescription = "Group with designated owner DJER0105"

Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $appId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint "your certificate thumbprint"

# Create the security group
$params = @{
    description = $groupDescription
    displayName = $groupName
    mailEnabled = $false
    mailNickname = $groupName.Replace(" ", "")
    securityEnabled = $true
}
$group = New-MgGroup -BodyParameter $params

# Assign the owner to the security group
$ownerUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$ownerObjectId"
$ownerRef = @{
    "@odata.id" = $ownerUrl
}
$ownerParams = @{
    "owners@odata.bind" = @($ownerRef["@odata.id"])
}
Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method PATCH "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$($group.Id)" -Body $ownerParams
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Using Microsoft Graph PowerShell authentication commands | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/authentication-commands?view=graph-powershell-1.0#using-client-credential-with-a-certificate)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why did you give Directory.AccessAsUser.All right to your service principal ? In my context I don't use signed user, I'm acting as application.

Comment: Hi @FernandoAhumada. I'm connecting with application using  Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $appId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint "your certificate thumbprint"

Comment: Yes me too, I'm not sure which difference between delegated and application type of permission.

Comment: Delegated permission...

Comment: Yes, I give mentioned right to my service principal and it works well now. I have to justify this right against the security officer, i'm looking for the description of this right but I don't understand why is required, i'm connected without user sign-in, I'm connected (as per my understanding) with my service principal. Do you have any input to understand why this right is required? Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Is the service princial using my credential?? I'm asking because the description says "Read and write directory objects (including navigation properties) on behalf of the signed-in user."